# Google Maps v3 get all lat/long between two lat long for moving a marker smoothly

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to move my marker (icon) from one location to another very smoothly. I am very near to do this. I want to do something like [this link](http://www.kmcgraphics.com/google/) in API v3.

Now, I have got all the lat/long from two locations, but still no smooth effect. Then I decided to get all lat/long between two lat/long, for example I got 1000 lat/long between two locations. Now I want lat/long between the first lat/long to the second lat/long of that 1000 lat/longs, that gives me more lat/long. Here is my code.

```
var map, ren, ser;
var data = {};
var marker;
function goma() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mappy'), {'zoom':6, 'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'center': new google.maps.LatLng(22.05678288577881, 72.30236816615798)});
  ren = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer( {'draggable':true} );
  ren.setMap(map); 
  ser = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  google.maps.event.addListener(ren, 'directions_changed', function(event){
    var waypoints = ren.directions.routes[0].legs[0].via_waypoints;
  });
  ser.route({
    'origin': new google.maps.LatLng(22.3000, 70.7800),
    'destination':  new google.maps.LatLng(23.0333, 72.6167),
    'travelMode': google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING},
    function(res,sts) {
      if(sts=='OK')
        ren.setDirections(res);
    })
  }
  function run(i,j) {
    if(i!=0 || j!=0) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }
    if(i<=ren.directions.routes[0].legs[0].steps.length) {
      if(j==ren.directions.routes[0].legs[0].steps[i].path.length) {
        j=0;
        i++;
      } else {
        j++;
      }
    }
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: ren.directions.routes[0].legs[0].steps[i].path[j],
      map: map
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
    setTimeout(function() {run(i,j);}, 2000);
  }
```

It works but not as I want. I just want smooth effect and also I'd like to find the distance I have passed and speed. Thank you.

Comment: Why have you never accepted the answers on any of your other 8 questions?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with "accept answer" stuff, Now I got it. And afterwords I will follow stack overflow rules and regulations.